# how to do zero padding al the lsb

Tags: vhdl

I would like to add zero at the lsb (zero padding). my input is

```
 m  :   IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0);
```

and another vector (lets say a) that his length is changing all the time.
I didn't manage doing that by using bitwise `"OR"` because the length is always not the same.

Comment: What do you mean by the length of 'a' changing all the time?

Comment: a is another vector. every time i use this part of the code his length is diffrenet. at the first time it will be 5 bits len and at the second time it will be 22 bits len, etc

Comment: The fastest solution is a barrel shifter in shift-left mode. See other posts for this topic: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551049/vhdl-n-bit-barrel-shifter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't know the length of a, but want to zero pad the LSB of the resulting vector b it to length of b.

```
b(b'left downto b'left - a'left) <= a;
b(b'left - a'left - 1 downto 0) <= (others => '0');
```

I hope I didn't mix up the - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, using a function might be cleaner. You could declare a function which takes N and produces a zero vector of that length. Here's an implementation:

```vhdl
function zeros(
    i_length : natural
) return std_logic_vector is
    variable v_zero_vector : std_logic_vector(i_length - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    return v_zero_vector;
end function;
```

One can then use this function in conjunction with the `&` operator. For example, I have a vector `a` and `b` and I want to zero pad `a` to fit into `b`:

```vhdl
b <= zeros(b'length - a'length) & a;
```