# How to shift std_logic_vector?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I want shift `std_logic_vector`.

But this code is has an error:

```
architecture led_main of testing is
    signal clk_cnt : std_logic_vector(64 DOWNTO 0) := (others => '0');
    signal led_buf : std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 ) := "0001";
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            clk_cnt <= clk_cnt + 1;
            if clk_cnt >= 24999999 then
                led_buf <= led_buf(0) & led_buf(3 downto 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    ground <= '0';
end led_main;
```

I think "0001", "0010", "0100" ...

Comment: this code led_buf <= led_buf(0) & led_buf(3 downto 1); change led_buf <= led_buf srl 1; (error)

Comment: Do you want to shift or rotate? Your question asks for shift, but your code shows rotate. Do you want an operation to the right or left, because your code is to the right, whereas your texts shows an example to the left!

Comment: @YannVernier No, a barrel shifter is an implementation form of a shifter that is very fast but also resource consuming. You can extend a barrel shift to also do rotations, but the barrel shifter describes the structure how to build a good shifter, not that it rotates. See this answer [n bit barrel shifter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551049/vhdl-n-bit-barrel-shifter) for the barrel shifter structure.

Comment: Ah. Pardon the confusion and thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shifter is OK. Actually, it's a rotator.

But your counter is to big (65 bits) and it doesn't roll over or reset to zero in a proper time. Your current design waits for 25M cycles and then shifts in every cycle from 25M to 2**64.

More over, you are using a non standard IEEE package to perform arithmetic operations (addition) on `std_logic_vector`. Please use type `unsigned` from package `numeric_std`.

The needed number of bits for your counter can be obtained by a `log2` function like this:

```
function log2ceil(arg : positive) return natural is
    variable tmp : positive;
    variable log : natural;
begin
    if arg = 1 then return 0; end if;
    tmp := 1;
    log := 0;
    while arg > tmp loop
        tmp := tmp * 2;
        log := log + 1;
    end loop;
    return log;
end function;
```

Source: [https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/utils.vhdl?ts=2#L341-L353)

**Full code rewrite:**

```
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

architecture led_main of testing is
    constant CNT_MAX : positive := 25000000;
    signal clk_cnt : unsigned(log2ceil(CNT_MAX) - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal led_buf : std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0 )           := "0001";
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            clk_cnt <= clk_cnt + 1;
            if clk_cnt = (CNT_MAX - 1) then
                clk_cnt <= (others => '0');
                led_buf <= led_buf(0) & led_buf(3 downto 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end led_main;
```

```