# Unable to synthesize code. GHDL throws an array bounds error

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I'm new to Stack Overflow and to VHDL too. I have completed the logic of an N-bit shifter and tested it using a testbench. But am unable to synthesize it.

While synthesizing I get an error saying "left and right bounds of a slice must be either constant or dynamic" (it is in line 37 and 45, also visible in the [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwBnT.png)). Can somebody please tell what I need to fix (and perhaps how)?

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use work.types.all;
use work.functions.all;
use work.casts.all;

entity logbarrel is
    generic (   N     : natural := 32
          );
    port    (   a     : in  std_logic_vector(N-1       downto 0); -- input data word
                func  : in  std_logic_vector(  2       downto 0); -- ctrl word (000=>>, 001=<<, 010=*>, 011=<*, 100=>>>)
                shamt : in  std_logic_vector(log2(N)-1 downto 0); -- shift amount
                y     : out std_logic_vector(N-1       downto 0)  -- output data word
          );
end;

architecture rtl1 of logbarrel is
    begin
        process(all)
      constant stage : natural := log2(N);                              -- number of stages
      variable rotr  : arr_of_slv(stage-1 downto 0)(N-1 downto 0);      -- rotated words
      variable mask  : arr_of_slv(    N-1 downto 0)(N-1 downto 0);      -- masks for all possible shifts
      variable sh    : std_logic_vector(shamt'range) := (others =>'0'); -- used as actual shift amount
            
        begin
  
    --   left or right shift
            if to_int(func) = 1 OR to_int(func) = 3 then  --checking for left, easier
                sh := (others =>'0'); --left makes sh = 000
            else
                sh := (0 => '1', others =>'0'); --right makes sh = 001
            end if;
      
      --  1st stage
            if shamt(0) = '1' then   -- shift if needed
                rotr(stage-1) := a(N*(1-to_int(sh))+2*to_int(sh)-2 downto 0) & a(N-1 downto N*(1-to_int(sh))+2*to_int(sh)-2+1); --rotate
            else 
                rotr(stage-1) := a; --no shift
            end if; 
  
      -- i-th stage 
            for i in stage-2 downto 0 loop
                if shamt(stage-i-1) = '1' then    -- shift if needed
                    rotr(i) := rotr(i+1)(N*(1-to_int(sh))+(2*to_int(sh)-1)*2**(stage-i-1)-1 downto 0) & rotr(i+1)(N-1 downto N*(1-to_int(sh))+(2*to_int(sh)-1)*2**(stage-i-1)); --rotate
                else
                    rotr(i) := rotr(i+1); --no shift at this level
                end if; 
            end loop;
            
      -- mask the rotated data if needed
            for i in 0 to N-1 loop
                case func is
                    when "000" | "100"  => mask(i) := (N-1 downto N-1-i+1 => '0') & (N-i-1 downto 0 => '1'); -- right shift
                    when "001"          => mask(i) := (N-1 downto i => '1') & (i-1 downto 0 => '0'); -- left shift
                    when "010" | "011"  => mask(i) := (others => '1'); -- rotate
                    when others => mask(i) := (others => '0'); -- this case 101 should not occur
                end case; 
            end loop;   
      
      -- output masking
            y <= (N-1 downto N-to_int(shamt) => a(N-1)) & (rotr(0)(N-to_int(shamt)-1 downto 0) AND mask(to_int(shamt))(N-to_int(shamt)-1 downto 0)) when func = "100" else         -- masking for arith. right shift
                    rotr(0) AND mask(to_int(shamt));                          -- masking for all other cases
        end process;
    
  end;
```

Here's the original code skeleton, on which I had to change the lines only where TODO was written

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use work.types.all;
use work.functions.all;
use work.casts.all;

entity logbarrel is
    generic (   N     : natural := 32
          );
    port    (   a     : in  std_logic_vector(N-1       downto 0); -- input data word
            func  : in  std_logic_vector(  2       downto 0); -- ctrl word (000=>>, 001=<<, 010=*>, 011=<*, 100=>>>)
                  shamt : in  std_logic_vector(log2(N)-1 downto 0); -- shift amount
            y     : out std_logic_vector(N-1       downto 0)  -- output data word
          );
end;

architecture rtl1 of logbarrel is
    begin
        process(all)
      constant stage : natural := log2(N);                              -- number of stages
      variable rotr  : arr_of_slv(stage-1 downto 0)(N-1 downto 0);      -- rotated words
      variable mask  : arr_of_slv(    N-1 downto 0)(N-1 downto 0);      -- masks for all possible shifts
            variable sh    : std_logic_vector(shamt'range) := (others =>'0'); -- used as actual shift amount
            
        begin
  
      -- left or right shift
            if TODO then  
                sh := TODO 
            else
                sh := TODO
            end if;
      
      --  1st stage
            if TODO then     -- shift if needed
                rotr(stage-1) := TODO
            else 
                rotr(stage-1) := TODO
            end if; 
  
      -- i-th stage 
            for i in TODO loop
                if TODO then    -- shift if needed
                    rotr(i) := TODO
                else
                    rotr(i) := TODO
                end if; 
            end loop;
            
      -- mask the rotated data if needed
            for i in 0 to N-1 loop
                case func is
                    when TODO   => mask(i) := TODO -- right shift
                    when TODO   => mask(i) := TODO -- left shift
                    when TODO   => mask(i) := TODO -- rotate
                    when others => mask(i) := TODO -- this case 101 should not occur
                end case; 
            end loop;   
      
      -- output masking
            y <=  TODO when TODO else         -- masking for arith. right shift
                        TODO                          -- masking for all other cases
        end process;
    
  end;
```

And here is the testbench used to test this as an instantiation. (It also initializes another such entity, I'll paste its code below, in case you want it).

```vhdl
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use work.casts.all;
use work.functions.all;

entity shifter_tb is
  generic( N    : natural := 32;
           ainit: natural := 16#72345678#);
end;

architecture test of shifter_tb is
  signal a, y1, y2 : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0):= to_slv(ainit,N); 
  signal func      : std_logic_vector(  2 downto 0);
  signal shamt     : std_logic_vector(log2(N)-1 downto 0);
begin

  stimuli: process
  begin
   -- for i in 0 to 2**a'length-1 loop  
    --  a <= to_slv(i, a'length);     
      for j in 0 to 4 loop --2**func'length-1 loop 
        func <= to_slv(j, func'length);
        for k in 0 to 2**shamt'length-1 loop
          shamt <= to_slv(k, shamt'length);         
          wait for 10 ns;
          case func is
            when "000"  =>  assert (y1 = y2)
                            report strs(y1) & strs(y2)  &  " = " & 
                                   str(a)  & " >> "  & strs(to_int(shamt))  & str(func)  ;
            when "001"  =>  assert (y1 = y2)
                            report strs(y1) &  str(y2)  &  " = " & 
                                   str(a)  & " << "  & strs(to_int(shamt))  & str(func)  ;
            when "010"  =>  assert (y1 = y2)
                            report strs(y1) &  str(y2)  &  " = " & 
                                   str(a)  & " *> "  & strs(to_int(shamt))  & str(func)  ;  
            when "011"  =>  assert (y1 = y2)
                            report strs(y1) &  str(y2)  &  " = " & 
                                   str(a)  & " <* "  & strs(to_int(shamt))  & str(func)  ;  
            when others =>  assert (y1 = y2)
                            report strs(y1) &   str(y2)  &  " = " & 
                                   str(a)  & " >>> " & strs(to_int(shamt))  & str(func)  ;                          
          end case;
        end loop;
      end loop; 
    --end loop;      
    wait;
  end process; 

  shifter1_inst: entity work.shifter
               generic map (N => N)
               port    map (a, func, shamt, y1); 
  shifter2_inst: entity work.logbarrel
               generic map (N => N)
               port    map (a, func, shamt, y2);                      
                            
end;
```

The other entity called shifter (the golden model):

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
use work.types.all;
use work.functions.all;
use work.casts.all;

entity shifter is
    generic (   N     : natural := 32
          );
    port    (   a     : in  std_logic_vector(N-1       downto 0);
            func  : in  std_logic_vector(  2       downto 0);
                  shamt : in  std_logic_vector(log2(N)-1 downto 0); 
            y     : out std_logic_vector(N-1       downto 0)
          );
end;

architecture rtl of shifter is
begin
    process(all)
        variable rotr, rotl, ashr, lshr, lshl : arr_of_slv(N-1 downto 0)(N-1 downto 0); 
    begin
                
        lshr(0) := a; lshl(0) := a; ashr(0) := a; rotr(0) := a; rotl(0) := a;
        for i in 1 to N-1 loop
            lshr(i) := (i-1 downto 0 => '0')    & a(N-1 downto i);
            lshl(i) := a((N-1)-i downto 0)      &  (i-1 downto 0 => '0');   
            ashr(i) := (i-1 downto 0 => a(N-1)) & a(N-1 downto i); 
            rotr(i) := a(    i-1 downto 0)      & a(N-1 downto i); 
            rotl(i) := a((N-1)-i downto 0)      & a(N-1 downto N-i);
        end loop;   
        
        y <=    lshr(to_int(shamt)) when func = "000" else
                    lshl(to_int(shamt)) when func = "001" else
                    rotr(to_int(shamt)) when func = "010" else
                    rotl(to_int(shamt)) when func = "011" else
                    ashr(to_int(shamt));
    end process;

end;
```

And finally the header files (not sure what they're called in the VHDL world) that are being used in the testbench and the instantiated architectures:

types:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package types is
  constant width : integer := 32;
  subtype byte         is       natural range 7 downto 0;
  subtype logic        is       std_logic;
  subtype byteT        is       std_logic_vector(byte);
  subtype word         is       std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
  subtype uword        is       unsigned(width-1 downto 0);
  subtype sword        is       signed  (width-1 downto 0);
  type arr_of_slv      is       array   (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
  type matrix          is       array   (natural range <>, natural range <>) of std_logic;
end;

package body types is

end;
```

functions:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.casts.all;
use work.types.all;

package functions is
  function log2  (a                      : natural)                             return natural;
  function replicate(s                   : std_logic; n: integer)               return std_logic_vector;
  function decode(arg                    : std_logic_vector)                    return std_logic_vector;
  function mux(sel, x                    : std_logic_vector)                    return std_logic;
  function mux(sel : std_logic_vector; x : arr_of_slv)                          return std_logic_vector;
 -- function mux(sel : std_logic_vector; x : arr_of_slv (0 TO M-1)(N-1 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
  function reduce(Inputs                 : std_logic_vector )                   return std_logic_vector;
  --function reduction( Inputs : arr_of_slv )                         return std_logic_vector;
end;  
  
package body functions is

  function log2 (a: natural) return natural IS
    variable val : natural := a;
    variable log : natural := 0;
  begin
    for i in a downto 0 loop
      val := val / 2;
      if val > 0 then
        log := log + 1;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return log;
  end;

  function replicate(s: std_logic; n: integer) return std_logic_vector is
    variable r : std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
  begin
    for i in 0 to n-1 loop
      r(i) := s;
    end loop;
    return r;
  end;

  function decode (arg : std_logic_vector) return std_logic_vector is
        variable res : std_logic_vector((2**arg'length)-1 downto 0);
    begin
        res(to_int(arg)) := '1';
        return res;
    end;

  function mux( sel, x : std_logic_vector ) return std_logic is  
  begin
     
    return x(to_int(sel));

  end;

  function mux( sel : std_logic_vector; x: arr_of_slv) return std_logic_vector is  
  begin

  --  assert Inputs'length <= 2 ** sel'length
  --    report "Inputs size: " & integer'image(Inputs'length) & " is too big for the select";
     
    return x(to_int(sel));

  end;

  -- function mux(sel : std_logic_vector; x : arr_of_slv (0 TO M-1)(N-1 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
  --   variable y : std_logic_vector(x(0)'length-1 downto 0);
  -- begin
  --     y := x(to_int(sel));  
  --   return y;
  -- end; 

  function reduce( Inputs : std_logic_vector ) return std_logic_vector is
    constant N   : integer := Inputs'length;
    variable inp : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
  begin
    inp := Inputs;
    if(N = 4) then
      return inp(1 downto 0) xor inp(3 downto 2);
    else
      return reduce(inp((N-1) downto N/2)) xor reduce(inp(((N/2)-1) downto 0));
    end if;
  end;

  -- function reduction( Inputs: arr_of_slv ) return std_logic_vector is
  --   constant N   : integer := Inputs'length;
  --   variable inp : arr_of_slv(N-1 downto 0, 12-1 downto 0);
  -- begin
  --   --return x"1234"; --Inputs(0);
  --   inp := Inputs;
  --   if N = 1 then 
  --      return inp(0); 
  --   elsif N > 1 then
  --      return reduction(inp(N-1 downto N/2)) xor reduction(inp(N/2-1 downto 0));
  --   end if;   
  -- end;    
end;
```

casts:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package casts is
  function to_int(arg: std_logic_vector)       return natural;
  function to_sint(arg: std_logic_vector)      return natural;
  function to_int(arg: unsigned)               return natural;
  function to_int(arg: signed)                 return natural;
  function to_slv(arg: integer; bits: integer) return std_logic_vector;
  function to_slv(arg: unsigned)               return std_logic_vector;
  function to_slv(arg: signed)                 return std_logic_vector;
  function to_slv(arg: std_ulogic_vector)      return std_logic_vector;
  function to_sslv(arg: integer; bits: natural) return std_logic_vector;

  function str(s: std_ulogic_vector)           return string;
  function str(s: integer)                     return string;
  function strs(s: std_ulogic_vector)          return string;
  function strs(s: integer)                    return string;
  function strs(s: std_logic)                  return string;
  function str(s: std_logic)                   return character;
end;

package body casts is
  
  subtype logic is std_logic;
  type logic_vector is array (natural range <>) of std_logic;

  function to_int (arg: std_logic_vector) return natural IS
  begin
    return to_integer(unsigned(arg));
  end;

  function to_sint (arg: std_logic_vector) return natural IS
    variable x : signed(arg'range);
  begin
    x := signed(arg);
    return to_integer(x);
  end;

  function to_int (arg: unsigned) return natural IS
  begin
    return to_integer(arg);
  end;

  function to_int (arg: signed) return natural IS
  begin
    return to_integer(arg);
  end;

  function to_slv(arg: integer; bits: integer) return std_logic_vector is
  begin
      return std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(arg,bits));
  end;

  function to_sslv(arg: integer; bits: natural) return std_logic_vector is
  begin
      return std_logic_vector(to_signed(arg,bits));
  end;

  function to_slv(arg: unsigned) return std_logic_vector IS     
  begin     
    return std_logic_vector(arg);    
  end;

  function to_slv(arg: std_ulogic_vector) return std_logic_vector IS     
  begin     
    return to_stdlogicvector(arg);    
  end;
  
  function to_slv(arg: signed) return std_logic_vector IS     
  begin     
    return std_logic_vector(arg);    
  end;

  function chr2sl (ch: in character) return std_logic is
    begin
      case ch is
        when 'U' | 'u' => return 'U';
        when 'X' | 'x' => return 'X';
        when '0'       => return '0';
        when '1'       => return '1';
        when 'Z' | 'z' => return 'Z';
        when 'W' | 'w' => return 'W';
        when 'L' | 'l' => return 'L';
        when 'H' | 'h' => return 'H';
        when '-'       => return '-';
        when OTHERS    => assert false
                          report "Illegal Character found" & ch
                          severity error;
                          return 'U';
      end case;
    end;
    
    function str2sl (s: string) return std_logic_vector is
      variable vector: std_logic_vector(s'LEFT - 1 DOWNTO 0);
    begin
      for i in s'RANGE loop
        vector(i-1) := chr2sl(s(i));
      end loop;
      return vector;
    end;

    function to_char(s: std_ulogic) return character is
    begin
      case s is
        when 'X' => return 'X';  
        when '0' => return '0';  
        when '1' => return '1';  
        when 'Z' => return 'Z';  
        when 'U' => return 'U';  
        when 'W' => return 'W';  
        when 'L' => return 'L';  
        when 'H' => return 'H';  
        when '-' => return '-';  
      end case;
    end;

  function str(s: std_ulogic_vector) return string is
    variable ret:string(1 to s'length);
    variable K  : integer:= 1;
  begin
    for J in s'range loop
      ret(K) := to_char(s(J));
      K := K + 1;
    end loop;
    return ret;      
  end;  

  function strs(s: std_ulogic_vector) return string is
  begin
    return str(s) & ' ';
  end;   

  function str(s: std_logic) return character is
  begin  
    return to_char(s);    
  end; 
  
  function strs(s: std_logic) return string is
  begin
    return str(s) & ' ';
  end; 

  function to_nstring(s: natural) return string is
    variable ret, iret : string(1 to 16);
    variable k, j      : integer;
    variable s1, s2, s3: natural := 0;
  begin  

    s1     := s;
    ret(1) := '0';  
    k      := 1;  
  
    while (s1 > 0 and K < 16) loop
      s2 := s1 / 10;
      s3 := s1 - (s2 * 10);
      if (s3 = 0) then 
        ret(k) := '0';
      elsif (s3 = 1) then
        ret(k) := '1';
      elsif (s3 = 2) then
        ret(k) := '2';
      elsif (s3 = 3) then
        ret(k) := '3';
      elsif (s3 = 4) then
        ret(k) := '4';
      elsif (s3 = 5) then
        ret(k) := '5';
      elsif (s3 = 6) then
        ret(k) := '6';
      elsif (s3 = 7) then
        ret(k) := '7';
      elsif (s3 = 8) then
        ret(k) := '8';
      elsif (s3 = 9) then
        ret(k) := '9';
      end if;
      k := k + 1;
      s1 := s2;
    end loop;
  
    if (k > 1) then
      k := k-1;
    end if;

    J := 1;
    while (k > 0) loop
      iret(j) := ret(k);
      k := k-1;
      j := j+1;
    end loop;        

    return iret;      

  end;


  function str(s: integer) return string is
  begin
    if (s < 0) then
      return "-" & to_nstring(-s);
    else
      return to_nstring(s);
    end if;    
  end;
 
  function strs(s: integer) return string is
  begin
    return str(s) & ' ';
  end;

end;
```

Comment: See [ask]. Image text doesn't show up in search, knowing the ghdl command line might, as well as declarations and bodies for to_int and for sanity log2. Use the [tag:ghdl] tag on your question.  There isn't enough here to replicate the problem.  From the image ghdl had an internal error reporting the error found at line 37. Appears you may have commented it out to reach line 45. Both bounds calculated for the slice names depend on variable sh. The synthesis tool likely conforms to IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (withdrawn) and isn't as sophisticated as some modern commercial offerings.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 8.6.5 Slice names "For a discrete range that appears as part of a slice name, the bounds of the discrete range shall be specified directly or indirectly as static values belonging to an integer type." For each element of shamt there'd be a 3:1 mux (left, right, no shift). The offsets are all powers of two, the masking/rotate can occur in mux inputs. Consider a concurrent for i in stage'range generate statement instead of a for loop . See [VHDL n-bit barrel shifter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551049/vhdl-n-bit-barrel-shifter).

Comment: @user16145658, I have added the GHDL tag, and yes, I had to go around line 37 to see if the problem is also in line 45. Turns out, the problem is also showing up in line 62. I agree this might be a limitation of the tool. Unfortunately, I can't use the concurrents, but rather the for-loops, since I need to submit this using the same template on which I am filling out these lines. Thanks a lot for your help though.

Comment: Neither "using the same template" nor the meaning of these operators `(000=>>, 001=<<, 010=*>, 011=<*, 100=>>>)` are apparent in the question. Without a [mcve] a potential answerer can't validate a solution (emphasis on minimal). Here the issue is to use slice names that don't depend directly on the values of variables (or signals). There are some number of methods including that alluded to in the absent error message ("dynamic") where the default class of a formal in a subprogram call parameter list of mode in is constant. A for loop can be used to evaluate  an element of shamt here.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the missing items earlier. I have added the original template (on which I am supposed to work), the testbench (to clear up how these =>> & *> operators are working) and other items (the header files) to the question. Sorry for not being minimal, can't afford to cut lines of code with my current level of expertise. Also, these operators are right & left shifts, rotates and arithmetic shifts. Thanks again, for the effort thus far.

Comment: Writing code for synthesis is quite different from writing code for simulation. You might imagine that the synthesizer must infer digital logic circuits from your code. You're asking it to dynamically change electrical connections based on some dynamic input. It cannot magically infer some mini robots that will cut some wires and solder them to other places. You could try to infer a dynamic bit-shifter, but you'll have to follow the specific coding guidelines required by the synthesizer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VHDL n-bit barrel shifter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551049/vhdl-n-bit-barrel-shifter)

Comment: @JHBonarius, hey thanks for the clarification about synthesis. As for the link you referred to, it was one of the first things I looked at before beginning the design. But, no, there were 2 examples, one was a fairly simple 32 bit one (I need an N-bit example) and the other one was where the coder had as many lines to use as he liked, unlike me, who has to fit my solution into the structures set by the instructor.

Comment: TBH if you're new to VHDL, your instructor should start simple and build up from there. This code is already quite complex. And in complex code it's easy to make mistake. There's probably some calculation error in your code, which causes the number of bits in the output to vary.

Comment: Haha. I'm glad to know this is "complex" per some definition. But, the error is not in the calculation, it runs and gives the desired output on the test bench.

Comment: Would never have guessed >>, <<, \*>, <\* and >>> referred to llvm assembler ops lshr, lshl, rotr, rotl and ashr without shifter.vhdl. We see JHBonarius can also be bit by the lack of a [mcve] and homework instructions. Note [ghdl synthesis](https://ghdl.github.io/ghdl/using/Synthesis.html) warning "This is experimental and work in progress! If you find crashes or unsupported features, please [report them](https://ghdl.github.io/ghdl/contribute.html#reporting-bugs)". It shouldn't 'crash', and may or may not already be reported and fixed.